# Calculate cgroups to run make on max cores/jobs

Tags: linux, makefile, virtual-machine, gnu-make

We are using a make file (generic one) and we have several of targets/recipe, which we want to run in [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html) 
this works when you running on your local machine and you are able to get the right number of the actual available cores however, when running on `cloud/vm` you can get more cores then you actually have and you can run into issue, is there a way to calculate the available cores or cgroups and linux vm machine?

this is what we use in the make file to calculate the cores

```
NPROCS = $(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)
MAKEFLAGS += -j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of my systems did support this `sysctl` call. I would use `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l` to get number of cores (this includes HT cores if enabled, resulting in 8 on a 4-core HT-enabled CPU).